# Empty dummy collections

Tags: autofixture

In this test, I expected dummyVar to be empty.  However, regardless of what I set OmitAutoProperty to, it is not.

Is this correct behavior and why?  What would be the *AutoFixture* way of creating an empty dummy collection?

```
[Fact]
public void ShouldBeEmpty()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    fixture.Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
    fixture.OmitAutoProperties = true;
    var dummyVar = fixture.Create<IEnumerable<IComparable>>();
    Assert.Empty(dummyVar);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [by design in AutoFixture 3.0](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/wiki/AutoFixture-3.0-Release-Notes#wiki-multiples). However, if you rather want enumerables to be empty, [you can configure that as well](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/80).

If you explicitly want only `IEnumerable<IComparable>` (but not other collections) to be empty, an easier way is to do this:

```
fixture.Inject<IEnumerable<IComparable>>(new IComparable[0]);
```

`OmitAutoProperties` control whether or not object *properties* (and fields) are populated or not. It doesn't affect the size of collections. (`IEnumerable<T>` defines no writable properties.)

`RepeatCount` controls the size of collections, but as [the previously mentioned issue](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/80) reports, you cant set `RepeatCount` to 0 (again by design).

Comment: Thanks Mark, I really like the simplicity of new IComparable[0].

Comment: @mark-seemann I think you linked to the wrong page in your reply wrt regarding AutoFixture 3.0, in part because both the anchor and corresponding link to that section on the Wiki page itself were broken.  AFAIK the correct link is https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/wiki/Version-History#various-collections-are-filled-by-default ... I also committed an update to the Wiki page itself.